# What is more effiencent or a better practice, creating a regular function or prototype function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

What is better practice for creating functions?

For example if I want to shuffle an array, is it a better application to just create a regular function or prototype function? Are there drawbacks/advantanges of using one over the other?

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
...
}
```

or:

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
..
}
```

Comment: What are your criteria for "better"?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, extending built–in prototypes is disliked because it can break for..in loops and may clash with future language extensions, noting that implementations can (and are encouraged to) extend the language independently of ECMA-262.

I doubt that the difference in performance is significant. It's more common to add the shuffle functionality to some object that needs shuffling than to the built–in Array prototype, though the generic code to shuffle something might be in a stand alone function and be re–used.

If you are going to add shuffling to an object, then prototype inheritance is a good choice as it is easily recognised and understood so maintenance should be easy. Also, it makes efficient use of memory and processing (though for a small number of functions the difference is trivial).

Comment: Of course, at the same time, using `for in` loops to iterate over an array is discouraged as well :)

Comment: Also, it might be worth it to mention that using `Object.defineProperty` (not supported in older browsers) can "fix" the enumerating problem if used correctly

Comment: @Jack—the main reasons not to use for..in with arrays are not related to enumerable properties on the prototype. It's because the order of enumeration is not guaranteed and non–numeric properties may be returned (including those on the prototype), which might be unexpected. It is also an indicator that an array may be being used where a plain object is more suitable. Otherwise, for..in iteration over arrays (e.g. sparse arrays) is fine, provided the risks are managed.

Answer (score 0):

Using prototype is better for object oriented design because it cannot be done on the fly. Also when using this notation `obj.member` it will check the non prototype version first. Prototypes allow for simulated inheritance, imo javascript is kinda just a bad language but I would say if you are trying to use good object oriented design it is better to use prototypes. Another thing you can do with prototypes is `a.__proto__` which will reference the original prototype of the object even if it has been modified

Answer (score 0):

Just make a regular function in this case. Not only is it simple, (and probably faster), but most importantly, it avoids messing with the global Array.prototype namespace.

The only really big advantage for prototype functions is when you need to do object orientation. Using the prototype method lets all instances share the same function while using closures will need to create a new coy of the function for each instance.